# UICollectionView cellForItemAt is called twice when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UICollectionView` with the following settings:

```
Estimate Size = None

Content Insets = Never

Scroll Direction = Vertical

Paging Enabled = true
```

When I scroll to the second cell, the `cellForItemAt` method is triggered twice, with indexes 1 and 2 at the same time, and accordingly, when I swipe to the last cell, the `cellForItemAt` method does not work.

1. `cellForItemAt` does not work correctly only on swiping to the second cell, in all other cases it is OK (one index per swipe)
2. I also noticed that `cellForItemAt` is triggered not as soon as a new visible cell appears, but with a delay (about 100 pixels on top, the standard height is 568 pixels of cells)

Because of this problem, I do not work `cellForItemAt` on the last cell, also in the cells there are photos that are loaded by URL (I tried without loading images, the problem is the same), and they are in random cells, this is also a problem.

I do not know how to explain and solve this issue, thank you for any help

**UP**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: TestCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TestCell.identifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cellForItemAt: \(indexPath.item)")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TestCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TestCell
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

If I scroll to the second cell, the `cellForItemAt` works twice, and when the last cell, the `cellForItemAt` does not work at all. Accordingly, the configuration methods for the last cell do not work. I gave a simple example, but the problem is the same.
How do I load a cell on a user's scroll correctly?

Comment: `cellForItem` can be called at any time and in any order. Your code should not have any requirement for a specific number of calls or order. What does "does not work correctly" mean? What should it do? What does it do? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Paulw11, why is it that when I scroll through one cell, I load two? And when I get to the last one it doesn't work at all, so the methods of the cell itself don't work correctly
Updated the question.

Comment: In your snippet nothing happens in `cellForItemAt `. You dequeue a cell and return it, that's it. What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As @PaulW11 said in his comment, your data source's `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method can be called at any time, with any indexPath. You should code your data source to provide any cell, for any valid indexPath, at any time, in any order.

The only limitation is that the collection view first calls your data source's `numberOfSections(in:)` and `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` methods, and won't ask for a cell for an indexPath that is out of the valid ranges indicated by those methods. Other than that, you should not make any assumptions about the cells the collection view will ask for, or the order in which it requests them.